# Center an element with another element?

Tags: php, css, alignment

Say I have code like such:

```
<div id="thisone">Content</div>
<div id="thatone">More Content</div>
```

Say both elements have a background color, so you can see their size, then is there a way to align the element with an id of #thisone according to the element with an id of #thatone? thanks!

(Edit: One of the elements has position:fixed, while the other is position:static)

Comment: What I mean is can I center one element with another, so the centre of both of the elements align?

Comment: @think123 - so you need dynamic allignment of the contents of div "thisone" with respect to div "thatone" right ?

Comment: If they're both within the same parent, they should be aligned automatically?

Comment: yes I need dynamic alignment, but not of the content of the elements, but the elements themself.

Comment: does it really matter if it is class or id?

Comment: I mean having the centres aligned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you maybe explain a little better what you are trying to achieve? As you have added the "center" tag, maybe you want something like this?

```
<style>
  #thisone {
    background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 80px;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
  }
  #thatone {
    background-color: blue; width: 200px; height: 80px;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
  }
</style>
<div id="thisone">Content</div>
<div id="thatone">More Content</div>
```

(Which should center both divs in their parent)

Comment: Are you sure that it is cross-browser?

Answer (score 0):

set width of boths div's as equal( any number of pixel you want) and then add text-align :center in style,css